# The location field should have a length constraint to avoid the profile box from getting shrunk

Tags: discussion

The location field should have a length constraint to avoid the profile box from getting shrunk. I just made it very long in my profile to illustrate this effect.

I am not sure whether it is a bug or by-design feature.